# Opening a Sub-Category in java Swing application

Tags: java, swing, awt

I have a single window which is divided into left pane/frame and right pane/frame.

Left pane occupies 30% of the screen and is having categories, alligned in vertical manner.

What i want is when i click on a category, the right pane should show something based on it(which is simple) and (this is the place where m stuck and need help) want the subcategories to be displayed just below the category, which is being clicked, pushing the other categories below the subcategories !

Any pointers as to how can i achieve this in my application.

I am using swing/awt for my application !

Comment: Perhaps look at [`JSplitPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/splitpane.html), [`JScrollPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) and the [layout managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html).

Comment: For your right pane, I'd suggest using a [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html), this would allow you to switch between views as needed.

Comment: are you suggesting that i should divide my left pane again into multiple panes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As how I understand your question, you want to create a tree of categories.
You might want to check this document out:

[JTree](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html)